# Chef-client not running automatically post bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra

Is there some way to set up the periodic chef-client runs during the bootstrap phase?

I can successfully bootstrap a client from the chef server, I can then manually run chef-client on the client node. I can even get the client to run periodically like so:

```
sudo chef-client -d -i 1800 -s 13
```

I'd like to apply that step during the bootstrap phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not install itself as a service. Use the [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook to do that.